# How to disable links in iframe in the provided src property?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe

When the user uploaded any pdf files to the website for displaying purposes I am using iframe component.

Here is the sample screenshot
[image]

Here is my iframe code

```
                <iframe
                  onLoad={this.showIframe}
                  className='iframe'
                  src={attachmentUrl}
                  height='97%'
                  width='100%'
                  title='document'
                />
```

and this is the related CSS code

```
 .iframe{
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
```

I want to disable only the hyperlinks in the pdf (which is coming from src) and when I turned the above CSS code
`pointer-events: none` automatically disables all the options like download, print, zoom in, zoom out.... but I want to disable only text in the pdf. Is there any way to disable the hyperlinks in the src prop? instead of disabling entire hyperlinks in the iframe or please suggest me the better approach to resolve the issue.

Please help me to resolve this issue as I am completely new to iframe.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Disable them IN the PDF. I doubt you have enough control over a PDF in an iFrame to only disable links

Comment: @mplungjan Is the pdf viewer not a plugin from browser? If so, then is it out of control from user I think.

Comment: In Chrome the PDFViewer is a JS file

Comment: @mplungjan is it possible to open in new tab?

Comment: I could not. I tried to use base target but that failed. Try to look [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=pdf+links+target+site:stackoverflow.com)